# aws cli and awcli driver in python : how to set the endpoint?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, minio

I am trying to use Tensorflow with S3 backend, using a local S3 server (running minio). It seems it uses awscli driver for s3 communication, so I had a closer look at the aws command line interface.
Right now, I could do the required configuration (in cacerts and .aws/config and .aws/credentials) to run aws this way

```
aws --endpoint-url https://my-minio-server:9000 s3 ls
```

I would like aws to asked this server by default, so that I could simply do

```
aws s3 ls
```

with no further option. How should I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful if you're still fighting with it but I'd still prefer a way to configure this on the AWS CLI end.  I haven't found that approach yet so....

Here's a bash hack that works if the `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`) is sourced, which is usually the case.  If that doesn't make sense, a quick search for something like `bash_profile and bashrc shell initialization` should get you some better info that I can give you.

Anyways, I'm sure there's lots of way better ways to do this but the idea here is to just call a similar function with a different name than the regular `aws` CLI command.  The new function adds in the endpoint URL if you're calling `s3` commands.

```
# ~/.bashrc
# can be called using same args as AWS CLI
awsep () {
    # show help message if no params are passed
    if [ "$1" == "s3" ]; then
        aws --endpoint-url="<your url>" "${@:-help}"
    else
        aws "${@:-help}"
    fi
}
```

and now you can call it, after you make sure you've sourced the file you added the function to; e.g.

```
$ . ~/.bashrc && awsep s3 ls
```

And if you don't like or aren't able to use some random new function you created, you can alway just use a similar hack, which seems even more ghetto.  The goal is to wrap up the regular `aws` CLI command.  The way to do that would be nearly identical to the first function you read up above.  The only difference is that you name your function `aws` instead of some name you come up with and you reference the *real* `aws` CLI from inside your function.

```
# ~/.bashrc
# can be called using same args as AWS CLI
aws () {
    # show help message if no params are passed
    if [ "$1" == "s3" ]; then
        /path/to/your/real/aws-cli --endpoint-url="<your url>" "${@:-help}"
    else
        /path/to/your/real/aws-cli "${@:-help}"
    fi
}
```

My `aws-cli` happens to be at something like `/Users/me/.pyenv/shims/aws` because I installed the AWS CLI with pip and I use `pyenv` to manage my Pythons.  Yours might be in a different spot but you can always find it by running something like `which aws`, before you create that function in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

I don't *think* the latter approach will bite you but hacks can have weird side effects and I'm certainly not an expert at bash, the AWS CLI, pip or any of the other parts and pieces involved but it works for me...

I hope it helps.

Comment: you can call `unset -f aws` to unset the function if required